# Loading CSV data into Aurora Serverles MySQL 5.6 DB Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, load, serverless, amazon-aurora

Aurora serverless needs to load data from a text file in S3. Currently this is not possible. What can be a work around as the web app user has to load data into the Aurora serverless DB.
I will be grateful for any valuable suggestions.
Regards,
PG

Answer (score 0):

The work around I had to do was to take a small EC2 linux instance we had, run some java code that wrappered the AWS cli s3 cp command using Runtime.getRuntime().exec to copy the file(s) from s3 I wanted down to the EC2 instance, then the java code ran a LOAD INFILE cmd of the file(s) into Aurora serverless.

The reason I wrote the wrapper around an aws cli s3 cp command (which was a bit of a hack) was b/c the Java AWS SDK for downloading s3 files is painful.  There is a 5GB limitation on the standard API you use for downloading s3 files via the SDK.  So you have to chunk the file to download it from s3 via another API.  Then after writing all the code to do this the performance was slow.  After spending a day or so writing it, I figured why not just wrapper the aws cli s3 cp command and let it take care of the 5GB limitations, multithreading, etc for me.  Also you can tweak various parameters in it to further improve throughput. Plus by using Runtime.getRuntime().exec you can check the return code from the aws cli cmd to verify if it executed correctly or not.